# Detailed Wi-Fi menu by default

Tags: macos, wifi

When you hold down the option key before clicking on the wi-fi menu, you get all sorts of detailed stuff about your current connection.

Is there any way of making this the default behaviour? A terminal command perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a workaround to go through and unfortunately involves paying for a software (unless you're aware of free alternatives)  but thought I'd throw it out there while looking for more details:

Using a program like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), you can record a Macro that will be the result of a string/hotkey.

I recorded as follows:

1. Hit record
2. Pressed and held <kbd>option</kbd> key.
3. Clicked on Wifi menubar
4. Stopped recording.

I then set up the trigger to be a hotkey (like <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) or a string like `wifio`. Both worked. Detailed Wifi menu was opened and waited for my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for trackpad users is using [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) (fortunately free):

To configure a gesture:

- Choose "Trackpads" (highlighted in orange in the screenshot below)
- Choose a touchpad gesture (highlighted in red)
- Choose predefined action -> Mouse Click Actions -> Option+Click (highlighted in green)

In my example below I have chosen a single finger tap at the top right of the trackpad to initiate an option-click.

This only works if BetterTouchTools runs. You may enable "Launch BetterTouchTools at start up" in simpe mode in the basic settings or in advanced mode in the settings.

[image: bettertouchtool]